# Is it possible to convert User Id to int in asp.net CORE?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Changing the user Id to int will help me add an Edit user page to be able to edit user infomration etc, but i having a problem with other functions in the app as they use string for the Id and not int. Here is what i have tried already:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<int>

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int>
```

by following this toturial [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-primary-key-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore2x)

This will work, but it messes up the Account and Manage controllers in the app, specially these lines:

```
var callbackUrl = Url.ResetPasswordCallbackLink(user.Id, code, Request.Scheme);

var callbackUrl = Url.EmailConfirmationLink(user.Id, code, Request.Scheme);

var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync(user.Id);
```

these give errors that say they can't convert from string to int, and that is understandable. Will this mean that it's not possible to convert the Id from string to int?

Comment: Check [method definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1.getexternallogininfoasync?view=aspnetcore-2.0). `GetExternalLoginInfoAsync (string expectedXsrf = null)` doesn't expect user id as parameter. It gets the external login information for the current login. As about `ResetPasswordCallbackLink` and `EmailConfirmationLink` methods - what stops you from doing `user.Id.ToString()` ?

Comment: Wow, i completely forgot about ToString. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

1. Check [method definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1.getexternallogininfoasync?view=aspnetcore-2.0). `GetExternalLoginInfoAsync (string expectedXsrf = null)` doesn't expect user id as parameter. It gets the external login information for the current login.
2. As about `ResetPasswordCallbackLink` and `EmailConfirmationLink` methods - you can simply do `user.Id.ToString()`.